# A extremely lazy girl that goes to the barber

Tags: kuro-kin-akanai-kagi

I remember watching a anime not to long ago. I don't remember anything but about what happed in the first episode. So I hope that is enough info.

What I remember of the first episode is it starting of with a girl laying in bed with extremely long hair. And I believe her brother came to the room to tell her not to go out of her room as he had just cleaned.

She decided to go outside for once. She was walking in the town looking for a barber, and she met some random guy here which takes her to a park and cuts her hair there. After which she went home without paying. After telling this to her brother he got pretty mad, saying she shouldn't trust people so easily and that she should go back to pay him for the hair cut.

and I believe her brother said something that pretty much stated you are mine, and mine alone in the end of the first episode.

Hope this is enough been looking around allot to find it again :)

Comment: not too long ago is 2-3 years? is it [Dansai Bunri no Crime Edge](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/the-severing-crime-edge)

Comment: @ShinobuOshino Nope that aint it. Im pretty sure it started off inside of a house as described I think she never left the house. And was always laying in bed.

Comment: What is the genre?

Comment: @Lex Not to sure, but believe it was slice of life.

Comment: oh its Rapunzel.

Comment: Do you remember her hair colour?

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko believe it was brown hair but I aint to sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By googling *anime hair cut in park* I got this:

[**Kuro to Kin no Hirakanai Kagi**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/16023/Kuro_to_Kin_no_Hirakanai_Kagi.)

The synopsis seems to match quite well with your description:

> Katagiri Kanade is a hikikomori who spent her days lazing off in her room. Her specialty is her broad imagination which often leads to various wild delusions. One night a weird cowboy guy appeared in her dream, saying that he's her heart's hero. Due to his encouragement, Kanade decided to try and go have a haircut the next day. It was then when she met a mysterious guy who cut her hair in the park, giving her courage to resume her school days.

Comment: OH, this sure looks allot like it. I'll check it out once I get home

Comment: [Nice zombie slaying](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/1063/27)! Keep it up!

Answer (score -6):

Like Shinobu Oshino said, it seems to be  Dansai Bunri no Crime Edge/The Severing Crime Edge.

It is a story about a short girl with extremely long hair that can be cut only by the hero. The hero decivde to come cut her hair everyday because it grows extremely fast.

Comment: Well, in the comment after you looked, Dimitri said that it wasn't Dansai Bunri no Crime Edge.